# Safari not computing image aspect ratios from width and height attributes

Tags: html, image, safari, aspect-ratio

I've recently implemented a lazy image loading feature on an image-heavy website, and have been having issues with reflow. I fixed the problem by manually specifying the image dimensions using the `width` and `height` image attributes, as below:

```
<img class="lazyload img-fluid" data-src"/path/to/image.jpg" width="200" height="400" />
```

It works great in every browser except Safari, but I'm confused because Safari 14 (and mobile Safari 14) [supposedly support computing aspect ratios based on the `width` and `height` attributes](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_img_aspect_ratio_computed_from_attributes).

None of my up-to-date macOS or iOS devices seem to recognize this feature in Safari, but they do in every other modern browser. The expected outcome is that the spot on the page where the `<img />` tag is located should be reserved (painted) based on the calculated aspect-ratio using the `width` and `height` attributes, to be later replaced by the `data-src` attribute via the lazy-loading plugin. In Firefox and Chrome (+ Chromium-based browsers), the space is reserved until the image is loaded (to prevent reflow); in Safari, the space is not reserved and the page shifts after the image is loaded.

Anyone have any clue as to what I'm doing wrong? I'm not worried about backwards compatibility (Safari doesn't support the feature in question before 14.0) or IE support, so this solution is perfectly fine for me until `aspect-ratio` becomes available in browsers other than Chrome. Safari is important, though, so I'll take any suggestions.

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem (Safari 14.0.2). Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: Tried to whip you up a small example, but the problem I'm having is best demonstrated through anchor links so I grabbed a template and whipped up a demo site (https://codepen.io/sulliops/full/QWdwRxx). Click on "Nav 4" in the navbar; on all of my Safari browsers, there's significant reflow (see my quick video at https://gyazo.com/da76046282965f7a32ed3d85cc7423df).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to a calculation error in Safari's WebKit API. The issue was reported on the WebKit Bugzilla ([report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=224197)), and was patched in [WebKit Changeset 276521](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/276521/webkit). Said changeset was merged and released with [Safari Technical Preview 125](https://webkit.org/blog/11680/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-125/).